# How can I disable or control one-click photo sharing in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, messages

When I tap the "share" button in the Photos app in iOS 14, it gives me a dialog like this (please excuse the crude privacy blocks):

[image: Share dialog]

The first row below the photo is a list of suggested recipients. As best I can tell these are a mix of local Airdrop and recent Messages contacts. A single tap on any of the Airdrop options sends the selected photos, pretty much instantly.

For someone clumsy like me, this is super dangerous. Sending a photo to the wrong person could be awkward, disastrous, or even dangerous.

Is there any way to turn these suggestions off? Or if that's not possible, can I at least control who goes in them?

Comment: ‘*A single tap on any of them sends the selected photos*’ That is only true for AirDrop options; other options require confirmation.

Comment: OT: Your privacy blocks aren't crude at all! They're geometrical, and of a single color. Well done!

Comment: @grg Nice to know! I thought I remembered them being one-click, but I was afraid to test it. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off these suggestions since iOS 14 in the settings.

- Open **Settings** and tap **Siri & Search**.
- Turn off **Suggestions when sharing**.

As of today, there is no way to control who appears in this list, you can only disable it.

Comment: That did the trick! I didn't guess that was a Siri feature so I would never have thought to look there. Thanks!